# $\| f \|=\vert f(0) \vert‎ + ‎\sup \vert f'(t) \vert$ defines a norm on $C^{1}[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Does $$\| f \|=\vert f(0) \vert‎ + ‎\sup \vert f'(t) \vert$$ defines a norm on $C^{1}[0,1]$‎, ‎which is the space of (real) functions on $[0,1]$ with continuous derivative? explain in detail
(Tanks from your answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember what needs to be shown.

1. For $f\in C^1[0,1]$, $\Vert f\Vert$ is a real number.
2. $\Vert f\Vert\ge 0$.
3. $\Vert f\Vert = 0$ implies $f=0$.
4. $\Vert \alpha f\Vert =|\alpha|\cdot\Vert f\Vert$
5. $\Vert f+g\Vert \le \Vert f\Vert+\Vert g\Vert$

Note that points 1, 2, 4, 5 follow from observing that the maps  $C^1[0,1]\to\mathbb R, f\mapsto f(0)$ and $C^1[0,1]\to\mathbb C^0[0,1], f\mapsto f'$ are linear and that $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is defined as the sum of norms on these spaces (absolute value on $\mathbb R$ and supremum norm on $C^0[0,1]$).
Point 3 follows because $f(0)=0$ and $f'=0$ implies $f=0$.